# How to kill process by process description

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, kill

1.my code kill process

```
foreach (Process s1 in Process.GetProcessesByName("test"))
                {
                    s1.Kill();
                }
```

2.my code check description

```
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\test\test.exe");
                label1.Text = ""+ ("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription);
```

Comment: You may try checking the processes's MainModule.fileName, which will show the path of binary being executed.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET

```
Dim FileDes As String = String.Empty '//FileDescription
        For Each x As Process In Process.GetProcesses
            If FileDes = x.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription Then
                x.Kill()
            End If
        Next
```

C#

```
string FileDes = string.Empty; //FileDescription
foreach (Process x in Process.GetProcesses) {
    if (FileDes == x.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription) {
        x.Kill();
    }
}
```